# PHP Exec PHP script from command line on Windows in the background

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a PHP page that I am executing from another PHP page like this - `exec('c:\php\php.exe processing.php > NUL ');`

The processing page has a SQL stored procedure that runs and takes awhile to complete after the stored procedure is complete the page then creates a .csv from the results and drops it into a directory.

This entire process works fine as long as it does not take too long to execute. If I am running it on a few thousand records it only takes like 3-5 minutes and completes fine. If I run it with like 20K records the process takes over 10 minutes to complete but is getting killed before it's done.

The speed is not the issue, we are fine with it taking awhile to run but somehow the script is getting killed. While it's running I can see the CLI process from the task manager in Windows but it seems like if it takes more than 10 minutes Windows is killing it or something.

I am just trying to figure out how I can run this without the process getting killed for taking too long.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `set_time_limit(0)` (see documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Setting time limit to 0 will remove any time limit.

Also, make sure you're not having any memory issue. If your script tries to allocate too much memory it will be killed anyway. You can check memory usage of your script with `memory_get_usage()` (see documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this but it's not helping. I've also been watching the RAM and it's no where near using too much RAM. It really seems like its something in Windows that's killing it. I did some more testing and its running a full 30 minutes before its killed.